# C++ Adding 1 to very small number?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I'm just trying to compute a good sigmoid function in C++ (and efficient). So i have to do something like:
`1/(1 + exp(-x))`

The problem is, when `X` becomes big (or even small), the result of `1 + e` turns to be 0 or 1

For example,
`1 + exp(-30) = 1`
But this is incorrect...

How can we add very small (or big) numbers easily and efficiently ?

**Datatype** I am using : double

Here is the **code snippet**:

```
double Quaternion::sigmoidReal(double v){
    return 1.0 / ( 1.0 + exp(-v) ) ; 
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What data types are you using?

Comment: Show your code for a precise answer.

Comment: My code is quite simple : `double Quaternion::sigmoidReal(double v){
return 1.0 / ( 1.0 + exp(-v) ) ;
 }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to set the precision of `cout`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(30);
    std::cout << (1 + exp(-30)) << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.000000000000093480778673438181
```

**Note:** Like people have noted in the comments, part of the output is noise (which at the time, I didn't consider). I was mostly just trying to demonstrate that you can put an arbitrary number into `setprecision`.

This has to do with the maximum amount of information that can be saved in 1 double. Part of the bits is used for the exponent, and part for the actual digits. A more *accurate* way would be to print the number like this (without setting the precision):

```
std::cout << 1 << "+" << exp(-30) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
1+9.35762e-14
```

Which still leaves the problem of saving a double with that actual value. However, it is possible, and wikipedia has a list of libraries that help with this: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software). The related article also has some more explanation.

Comment: Ok so it was working, but i couldn't see it using the standard precision ? ^^ Thanks

Comment: If you really want to understand floating-point, you should at least begin by understanding machine epsilon. Look it up in wikipedia, a double has machine epsilon of 1.11e-16.

Comment: Um, the numbers in that output are mostly noise. Once you get beyond about 15 digits you're seeing noise.